# Get Minimum and Maximum Millisecond For Year in Moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Given a javascript function that takes a year, how do I get the minimum and maximum milliseconds for that year. (i.e. minimum being Jan 1 (Year) at 00:00.000 and maximum being Dec 31 11:59:59.999)?

Do I need to create a string representing those values and parse them, or is there a simpler method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With moment (using [`endOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/) and [`valueOf()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp-milliseconds/)):

```js
function getMinMillis(year){
  return moment({y: year}).valueOf();
}
function getMaxMillis(year){
  return moment({y: year}).endOf('year').valueOf();
}
console.log(getMinMillis(2018), getMaxMillis(2018));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

With native JavaScript Date:

```js
function getMinMillis(year){
  return new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf();
}
function getMaxMillis(year){
  return new Date(year, 11, 31, 23, 59, 59, 999).valueOf();
}
console.log(getMinMillis(2018), getMaxMillis(2018));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a function like this, using January 1, 12:00 a.m. and December 31, 11:59 p.m. as reference points:

```js
function getMinMaxMilliseconds(year) {
    // Get seconds of January 1, 12:00 a.m. of that year.
    let minMilliseconds = new Date(year, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime();
      
    // Get seconds of December 31, 11:59 p.m. of that year.
    let maxMilliseconds = new Date(year, 23, 31, 11, 59, 59, 999).getTime();

    // Return as an object (you could change this to whatever format you like).
    return { minMilliseconds, maxMilliseconds };
}


// Example:

console.log(getMinMaxMilliseconds(2018));
```

Comment: +1 for the native JavaScript solution, but note that you have to use `23` instead of `11` for hours and you inverted seconds and millis in `maxMilliseconds`.

Comment: @VincenzoC Thanks! I've fixed those issues now.

Answer (score 1):

Moment has the startOf() and endOf() methods which can be used in the following way to get the milliseconds at start and end of a given year.

```
function getMillisecondRangeForYear(year) {

    var date = moment({y: year});

    return {
        "min": date.startOf("year").valueOf(),
        "max": date.endOf("year").valueOf()
    };
}
```

Comment: This will give Deprecation warning, do not use `moment(String)` with non ISO 8601/RFC 2822 format

Answer (score 0):

You could create a date object as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. 
For example:

```
   new Date(yearInput, 1 [, 1 [, 0 [, 0 [, 0 [, 0]]]]]);
```

would create a date object for the minimum.